# java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inject members

Tags: java, mysql, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying since some time to get Arquillian running with JPA.

I had some DAO tests working, but while a continued to write the remaining tests this error started and affected both the ones I was writing and the ones that were fine before.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inject members

```
at org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.cdi.CDIInjectionEnricher.injectClass(CDIInjectionEnricher.java:117)
at org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.cdi.CDIInjectionEnricher.enrich(CDIInjectionEnricher.java:71)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestInstanceEnricher.enrich(TestInstanceEnricher.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:116)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.before(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:200)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:350)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:215)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7$1.invoke(Arquillian.java:279)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.BeforeLifecycleEventExecuter.on(BeforeLifecycleEventExecuter.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:116)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.fireCustomLifecycle(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:159)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7.evaluate(Arquillian.java:273)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:166)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:350)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:177)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:115)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.container.JUnitTestRunner.execute(JUnitTestRunner.java:61)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.executeTest(ServletTestRunner.java:139)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.execute(ServletTestRunner.java:117)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.doGet(ServletTestRunner.java:86)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1349)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.ArquillianProxyException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException : WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type MorphologicalAnalysisPersistenceFacade with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject br.com.cpmh.beacon.persistence.MorphologicalAnalysisPersistenceFacadeTest.morphologicalAnalysisPersistenceFacade
  at br.com.cpmh.beacon.persistence.MorphologicalAnalysisPersistenceFacadeTest.morphologicalAnalysisPersistenceFacade(MorphologicalAnalysisPersistenceFacadeTest.java:0)
 [Proxied because : Original exception caused: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.createInjectionTarget(BeanManagerImpl.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.createInjectionTarget(ForwardingBeanManager.java:204)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.cdi.CDIInjectionEnricher.injectNonContextualInstance(CDIInjectionEnricher.java:124)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.cdi.CDIInjectionEnricher.injectClass(CDIInjectionEnricher.java:110)
    ... 135 more
Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.ArquillianProxyException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException : WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type MorphologicalAnalysisPersistenceFacade with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject br.com.cpmh.beacon.persistence.MorphologicalAnalysisPersistenceFacadeTest.morphologicalAnalysisPersistenceFacade
  at br.com.cpmh.beacon.persistence.MorphologicalAnalysisPersistenceFacadeTest.morphologicalAnalysisPersistenceFacade(MorphologicalAnalysisPersistenceFacadeTest.java:0)
 [Proxied because : Original exception caused: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:378)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:290)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateProducer(Validator.java:425)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.InjectionTargetService.validateProducer(InjectionTargetService.java:36)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.validate(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:153)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:81)
    ... 140 more

My tests look all the same:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MorphologicalAnalysisPersistenceFacadeTest
{
    @Inject
    MorphologicalAnalysisPersistenceFacade morphologicalAnalysisPersistenceFacade;

    @Inject
    private UserTransaction userTransaction;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "BeaconAnalysis")
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment()
    {
        JavaArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "morphological-analysis-data-access-object-test.jar");
        archive.addPackages(true, "br.com.cpmh.beacon");
        archive.addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml");
        archive.addAsResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"));

        return archive;
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        //morphologicalAnalysisPersistenceFacade = new MorphologicalAnalysisPersistenceFacade();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception
    {
    }

    @Test
    public void create()
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most important part in this stacktrace is:

> WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type MorphologicalAnalysisPersistenceFacade

This usually means that not all required dependencies for *MorphologicalAnalysisPersistenceFacade* are deployed to the Weld-container. To debug this I would suggest temporarily rewriting your deployment method to:

```
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    JavaArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "morphological-analysis-data-access-object-test.jar")
    .addPackages(true, "br.com.cpmh.beacon")
    .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
    .addAsResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"));

    // print all included packages
    System.out.println(archive.toString(true));

    return archive;
}
```

This will print out all the classes which are deployed to the container. With that, you can investigate if any required class does not get deployed and include that class or package manually in your createDeployment method.